# PyCharm PostgreSQL dialect detection

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, pycharm, postgis

Having a problem with PostgreSQL dialect in PyCharm. I have the below `SELECT` query:

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE ST_DWithin(table.geog_column,
ST_GeographyFromText(\'SRID=4326;POINT(%s %s)\'), %s)"
```

The query performs as expected in a query editor but Pycharm complains `<expression> expected, got '%'`. I have set the dialect detection to PostgreSQL.

I believe there is an issue with the parameter binding but not able to figure out what the issue is. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I somehow missed the clear warnings on psycopg2 documentation about using python string interpolation and concatenation.

The right way of doing it is to use SQLAlchemy to construct raw SQL queries:

```
from sqlalchemy import text

sql = text("SELECT * FROM table WHERE ST_DWithin(table.geog_column,
ST_GeographyFromText(\'SRID=4326;POINT(:long :lat)\'), :distance)")
data = {'long': longitude, 'lat': latitude, 'distance': distance}
result = conn.execute(sql, data)
```

---

The below approach is WRONG and is susceptible to SQL injections. I have left it here for reference only.

I just found the mistake and for anyone else who is caffeine starved, you need to add the `%s` within single quotes. Elementary but can easily be missed.

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE ST_DWithin(table.geog_column,
ST_GeographyFromText(\'SRID=4326;POINT('%s' '%s')\'), *'%s'*)"
```

The quotes fixed the issue for me but I am not entirely sure if this is the right approach and hence leaving it here to get some input.